# prevent jump to top jquery tab function on click anchor

Tags: jquery, tabs, anchor

I have found this really great Tab Function in the I-net. I have read about the standard problem when using anchors: The Windows jumps to top. Altough there is a e.PreventDefault() and a Live Eventlistener integrated, it is still jumping to top when clicking on the tab. Could you give me an advice?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.tabs').each(function () {
        var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
        $active = $links.first().addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));

        $links.not(':first').each(function () {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        });

        // Binde den click event handler
        $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
            // Mache den alten Tab inaktiv
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $content.hide();
            $active = $(this);
            $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.fadeIn(800);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try starting with e.preventDefault(); when you're binding the click event.

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors in your browser's console?

Comment: I have included e.preventDefault(); at different places, but it has not solved the problem.

Comment: No unfortunately there are no JavaScript errors in the browser´s console

Answer (score 1):

Search for `event.preventDefault`, `stopPropagation` and **`return false`** (tested a lot of time)
and also, change the HREF to `javascript:void(0)` (if you can)

e.preventDefault could not do the trick sometimes. The best way i found is to add return false at the end of the function called onclick.

```
        // Binde den click event handler
        $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // Mache den alten Tab inaktiv
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $content.hide();
            $active = $(this);
            $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.fadeIn(800);
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;;
        });
```

Comment: Please, consider to add comment when you downvote... How can i improve myself this way?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I do have a bit of a problem with the "e.preventDefault could not do the trick sometimes." statement, because you haven't explained when "sometimes" is and because it doesn't match up with my experience (calling `e.preventDefault()` has always worked correctly for me).

Comment: Ok, I may remember this. For my part, I found that adding `return false` is a good way. For information, i don't remember exactly the context, but for some reasons, It's already arrived that just used preventDefault wasn't working... was it browser, function,... I don't know. Sorry if I can't be more accurate.

Comment: Hello, It's a little far-fetched, but try to add `onclick='return false;'` directly in `<a>` attribute of the tab. And could you add an href example... (Is it like this : #somethink ?)